# Generate 10-min interval start and end times in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a task where I need to generate 10-min interval between the given time range. For example,

**start_time** = '2020-09-02 17:33:04.472',
**end_time** = '2020-09-02 20:19:14.859'

**Desired Output:**

```
start_times_list = ['2020-09-02 17:30:00', '2020-09-02 17:40:00', '2020-09-02 17:50:00', '2020-09-02 18:00:00', '2020-09-02 18:10:00', '2020-09-02 18:20:00', '2020-09-02 18:30:00', '2020-09-02 18:40:00','2020-09-02 18:50:00', '2020-09-02 19:00:00', '2020-09-02 19:10:00', '2020-09-02 19:20:00', '2020-09-02 19:30:00', '2020-09-02 19:40:00', '2020-09-02 19:50:00', '2020-09-02 20:00:00', '2020-09-02 20:10:00', '2020-09-02 20:20:00']

end_times_list = ['2020-09-02 17:40:00', '2020-09-02 17:50:00', '2020-09-02 18:00:00', '2020-09-02 18:10:00', '2020-09-02 18:20:00', '2020-09-02 18:30:00', '2020-09-02 18:40:00','2020-09-02 18:50:00', '2020-09-02 19:00:00', '2020-09-02 19:10:00', '2020-09-02 19:20:00', '2020-09-02 19:30:00', '2020-09-02 19:40:00', '2020-09-02 19:50:00', '2020-09-02 20:00:00', '2020-09-02 20:10:00', '2020-09-02 20:20:00', '2020-09-02 20:30:00']
```

I have tried the below method which creates only a date range from start datetime, but not from the floor(min)

```
import pandas as pd

l = (pd.DataFrame(columns=['NULL'],
                  index=pd.date_range('2020-09-02 17:33:04', '2020-09-02 20:19:14',
                                      freq='10T'))
       .between_time('07:00','22:00')
       .index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
       .tolist()
)
l
```

**Current Output**

```
['2020-09-02 17:33:04',
 '2020-09-02 17:43:04',
 '2020-09-02 17:53:04',
 '2020-09-02 18:03:04',
 '2020-09-02 18:13:04',
 '2020-09-02 18:23:04',
 '2020-09-02 18:33:04',
 '2020-09-02 18:43:04',
 '2020-09-02 18:53:04',
 '2020-09-02 19:03:04',
 '2020-09-02 19:13:04',
 '2020-09-02 19:23:04',
 '2020-09-02 19:33:04',
 '2020-09-02 19:43:04',
 '2020-09-02 19:53:04',
 '2020-09-02 20:03:04',
 '2020-09-02 20:13:04']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Timestamp.round()` to round the start/end times to 10 minutes.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

start_time = '2020-09-02 17:33:04.472'

end_time = '2020-09-02 20:19:14.859'
  
start_times = pd.date_range(start= pd.Timestamp(start_time).round('10T'), end = pd.Timestamp(end_time).round('10T'), freq="10T")

end_times = start_times + pd.Timedelta('10T')

start_times_list = start_times.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tolist()

end_times_list = end_times.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tolist()

print(start_times_list)
print(end_times_list)
```

Comment: This works for only the above start time i.e. if the start time is  '2020-09-02 17:37:04.472', the list start time is showing from '2020-09-02 17:40:00'. Your round function is taking ceil and floor, but I always want floor(min) for start time.

Comment: It should be floor instead of round for my usecase, thanks though!

Comment: I actually wondered if that would be a problem - should have asked for clarification. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the input format, probably the most easy is to use:

```
newstarttime = starttime[:-8]+"0:00.000"
```

Comment: Starttime is always dynamic and it changes! @DriesDS

Comment: Yes, but the format stays the same, no?
Or is there another problem that you can't use this solution? @SakethGaruda

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import math

start_time = '2020-09-02 17:36:04.472'

end_time = '2020-09-02 20:19:14.859'
  
start_times = pd.date_range(start= pd.Timestamp(start_time).floor('10T'), end = pd.Timestamp(end_time).floor('10T'), freq="10T")

end_times = start_times + pd.Timedelta('10T')

start_times_list = start_times.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tolist()

end_times_list = end_times.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tolist()

print(start_times_list)
print(end_times_list)
```